# How to install pdfcol.sty

Tags: pdftex, python, tlmgr

I'm trying to download a jupyter notebook to a pdf and have downloaded almost all the various packages it said I needed. Most recently, I got the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `pdfcol.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.23 \pdfcolInitStack
                     {tcb@breakable}^^M
No pages of output.
Transcript written on notebook.log.
```

When I try downloading pdfcol by doing tlmgr install pdfcol, I get the following:

```
tlmgr: package repository https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr install: package pdfcol not present in repository.
tlmgr: action install returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

Any solutions??

Comment: pdfcol.sty is in  the oberdiek package.

Comment: I have the oberdiek package installed already, but still get the error that it's not found

Comment: if you have the tlmgr oberdiek package installed then  pdfcol will be /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdfcol.sty

Comment: To your .bashrc or .zshrc (whatever shell you use) on mac/linux, you need to add export PATH=<yourpathto>/TinyTeX/bin/universal-darwin:$PATH . also read all this thread (https://gist.github.com/peterhurford/75957ba9335e755013b87254ec85fab1) and make sure you are installing everything. I had to do sudo tlmgr --repository http://www.texlive.info/tlgpg/ install tlgpg to install tlgpg for example.

Comment: Also pdfcol is a separate package now.